# PHP Script ends before timeout without error

Tags: php, time, timeout

I have a PHP Script, it needs execution time of at least 1000 seconds to complete.

It terminates after around 265 seconds each time with no errors. Since I am using loops I tested number of iterations and it is independent of that, further ruling out a possibility of occurrence of an error in the loop.

I have set max_execution_time to 10800 in php.ini, and also changing memory_limit doesn't affect the results.

Please help! I have scratched my head thoroughly!

Comment: What does your code do? Are you sure no error is thrown? Have you set error display to E_ALL? Have you not suppressed any error with the `@` operator?

Comment: Sure it throws no errors. Did you look into log files?

Comment: are you running this from a command line, cron job, web server, other? have you tried a different method of invocation?

Comment: Also, try using the ini_get function http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-get.php to make sure the values have actually been changed!

If they haven't maybe you forgot to restart apache, or edited the wrong php.ini file.

Comment: +1 on @didnh's point. If a web request, then your environment might have a [RLimitCPU](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu) set.

Comment: It basically compares two set of strings, can't provide with more detail. error_reporting is set to E_ALL. No error has been suppressed.
I am running it via web server, haven't tried with any other method of invocation, might not be able to either because it collects a huge set of POST data from previous page.
The phpinfo() reflects the changes to php.ini

Comment: How do I check with RLimitCPU??

Comment: @AshishAgrawal dldnh asked **are you running this from a command line, cron job, web server, other?**  .... answer for that

Comment: Thanks guys for help! I was running on a *Web Server* as I have mentioned in previous comment.
Problem was Maximum Resource used allowed on the server by the host.
Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your log file? If you get error 6 or segmentation fault. Then your script is is actually crashing php without showing any errors on the browser (if it is browser and not cli).

If you are using apache on unix, then you should find this log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Otherwise you can define the path of the log file in `.htaccess` by add this line:

```
php_value error_log "/path/to/somewhere/convenient/php_errors.log"
```

Change the path to somewhere where your httpd has write permission and where you have read permission.

Comment: Hmm yeah I guess Segmentation faults will remain in HTTP servers log file. As php has already crash. Did you try looking into apache error log? or which HTTP server are you using?

Comment: The server log files weren't allowed on the Plesk I was given. The hosting provider confirmed that it was because of limitation of maximum resource allowed to be used by a single script.
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

give:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

in the beginning of script. so that the code execution will not time out unless its completed.

Comment: I m sorry for not being able to show the code... Its a private project..
But I have specified the most of the problem.. I have checked my code in different ways.. and it is good.. for smaller iterations it works well..

Comment: @AshishAgrawal **set_time_limit** has worked for me.. i have got codes to run for **30 - 40 mins without timeout**. showing **some code** may help to **fix the issue**.

Comment: Yes, indeed it has worked for me as well.
I got the problem answered.
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

This same error happened to me.  One of my PHP functions died without any errors sent to stderr, stdout, nor any other log file.

What happened was I was using a helper PHP script written by some other developer that was setting the memory limit to 512MB half way through the operation of my program.  The sub module poisoned the well by also setting the error log settings to silent at some point mid-way through the processing of my script.

You can prove if this is happening to you by printing out the php system settings available to your PHP script on EVERY iteration of the loop.  When the subscript did the dirty deed, the PHP engine throws a fit after the garbage collector runs at a random point in the future, then dies immediately without error.  It's a bug in the PHP garbage collector when sub modules mess with system settings as the garbage collector is doing its work.

**Solution:** Edit the php helper sub-modules, and make sure they don't tweak the system settings, as the garbage collector is doing its work.  The PHP interpreter will freak out and die without any errors or output at a random interval after the poisoning of the PHP system variables.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP, the only way to hide errors from logs even when the [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) are properly indicated is to use the [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php),

for example: the following code will raise a Fatal error but a "hidden" one, it will not appear neither on the logs or on the browser.

```
@echo "forgetting the last quote;
```

So set the display_errors value to On and the error_reporting depending on the PHP version you are using (see differences [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)), and check if you are using a "@" symbol on your code.